# How to select multiple maximum values in a text from sqlite table

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-room

I'm trying to select the five  previous words in an ordered text column but the query I'm using only returns only the immediate previous word

```
SELECT MAX (word) FROM wordsTable WHERE word < someword
```

What query can i use to return the previous five rows?
(Without using lag() or lead() functions)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `order by` and `limit`:

```
select word
from wordstable
where word < $word
order by word desc
limit 5;
```

Comment: Sir, will this be efficient for a table having a million rows since, by my limited understanding, this query returns all the words that are less than the specified word before limiting the result set by five?

Comment: If you have an index on `(word desc)` this should use the index.

Comment: Yes, i do. Thank you!